# HTML5 Audio, separate left and right channels

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have an mp3 file with 2 channels, right and left.

Is there is any way to play it in the browser with the two channels separated ?

So I will have two `<audio>` elements, one per each channel.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you trying to do this?  Using Web Audio, you can split the channels apart (via the ChannelSplitterNode) and process them separately.

Comment: I have audio processing results that I get from the server, and I get different results per channel. I should virtualize them in the client with an option to play the selected channel alone, or all of them.

Comment: Ah.  Then yes, you can use a ChannelSplitter node to mask out a channel (just don't connect it), or process them separately and re-merge to stereo using a ChannelMerger.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to separate the stereo audio file into two audio files, one with just the left channel, and one with just the right.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking to for, how can I do it ?

Comment: I did this by splitting audio tracks in Audacity, then exporting each separately. You'll have to download it and it's important to note that this will have a bit of a timing difference (even if you do `audio1.play(); audio2.play()`, so it will always have a bit of lag.